# PHP array_search not working when deleting entries

Tags: php, arrays, random

This sample code is giving me a headache. I'm trying to get 2 random values from the array. Delete the 2 entries that was chosen, and then continue until all elements is chosen. My problem is that the first 1-2 picks works fine, but then is chosen values that's not in the array, some times the same value is chosen 2 times...when removing the 2 unset-lines the code is ok...
I belive it's about the reindexing of the array after deleting, but the line "$number=array_values($number)" should do the job...

```
    <?php

$number=array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);//range(1,10);

//var_dump($number)." - ";//

for ($p = 1; $p <= 5; $p++) {
    echo "Nr. :".$p."</br>";
    echo implode(",",$number)."</br></br>";

    $udtrak = array_rand($number,2); // udvælger 2
    $pos[0] = array_search($udtrak[0], $number);
    $pos[1] = array_search($udtrak[1], $number);
    echo "Number: ".$number[$pos[0]]." Found at: " . $pos[0]."</br>";
    echo "Number: ".$number[$pos[1]]." Found at: " . $pos[1]."</br>";

    //unset($number[$pos[0]]);
    //unset($number[$pos[1]]);
    //var_dump($pos);    

$number=array_values($number);

echo implode(",",$number)."</br></br>";
} // for $p


?>
```

Comment: Show an example of your expected output.

Comment: Why not shuffle once at the start and then just pull two elements off the front each iteration?  Then there will be no duplicates, ever.

Answer (score 1):

[array_rand()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-rand.php) returns an array of keys. 
[array_search()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-search.php) searches by value and returns the key, if the value is found in the input.

So your code snippets selects random keys of `$number` and then searches values that equal that key. Thats not what you want.

Theres no need for array_search, simply use the keys that `array_rand()` selects:

```
$number=array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);//range(1,10);
for ($p = 1; $p <= 5; $p++) {
    echo "Nr. :".$p."</br>";
    echo implode(",",$number)."</br></br>";

    $pos = array_rand($number,2);
    echo "Number: ".$number[$pos[0]]." Found at: " . $pos[0]."</br>";
    echo "Number: ".$number[$pos[1]]." Found at: " . $pos[1]."</br>";

    unset($number[$pos[0]]);
    unset($number[$pos[1]]);

    $number=array_values($number);

    echo implode(",",$number)."</br></br>";
} // for $p
```

Comment: Hi Simon. Thanks a lot. I'll give it a try this evening.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to see any chance of duplication, just shuffle the array once from the start and output the data in pairs.  No `counters` required.  This also does not remove any array elements, so you can re-use them again "downscript".  My method employs the "Don't Repeat Yourself" principle of coding and makes no iterated function calls (well, I guess it does while sorting).

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/62c1a1cfedd83444ed6045b815fe1515f982d6ed))

```
$numbers=array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);//range(1,10);
uksort($numbers,function(){return rand()>rand();});  // shuffle and preserve indexes
//var_export($numbers);
$pairs=array_chunk($numbers,2,true);  // pair the values together (preserving indexes)
//var_export($pairs);
foreach($pairs as $pair){
    foreach($pair as $index=>$value){
        echo "Number: $value Found at: $index\n";
    }
}
```

Possible Output:

```
Number: 2 Found at: 1
Number: 1 Found at: 0
Number: 5 Found at: 4
Number: 3 Found at: 2
Number: 6 Found at: 5
Number: 4 Found at: 3
Number: 7 Found at: 6
Number: 8 Found at: 7
Number: 10 Found at: 9
Number: 9 Found at: 8
```

...hmm, perhaps a more efficient sort would be:

```
$mid=getrandmax()/2;
uksort($numbers, function()use($mid){return rand()>$mid;});  // shuffle and preserve indexes
```

---

And finally, if you want to leave the input totally untouched, shuffle an array of indexes instead. (This is probably my most recommended option)

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7f3156132a7e8daf36ed6eacb1db62ed1bd8e6ee))

```
$numbers=array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);//range(1,10);
$indexes=array_keys($numbers);  // store indexes as values
shuffle($indexes);
$pairs=array_chunk($indexes,2);  // group indexes by two
foreach($pairs as $pair){
    foreach($pair as $index){
        echo "Number: {$numbers[$index]} Found at: $index\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: *This also does not modify/destroy the input array* -- however, it does change the order of the items (which sounds like modifying to me).

Comment: Hi - I'm trying to simulate a game where the difference between the two chosen values is to be set in the array. So there have to be duplicate values later on...

Comment: Later on, but not in this loop?  Please offer more details so that I can deliver the best advice.

Comment: @steen are you going to explain your last comment?  Where is this question going?